# Why is the Fortran DO loop index larger than the upper bound after the loop?

Tags: loops, fortran

I am looking inside the code of an air quality model written in fortran, and have some questions regarding the way fortran passes variables out from do-loops.

This very simple example illustrates what I mean:

```
   PROGRAM carla
   IMPLICIT NONE
   !
   INTEGER, PARAMETER :: LM = 24, DEZASSEIS = 16
   INTEGER            :: L, VARIAVEL, SOMA
   !
   DO L=1,LM
   WRITE(*,*) 'L = ', L
   END DO
   !
   WRITE(*,*) 'I am now ouside of the DO loop.'
   WRITE(*,*) 'I would expect L=LM=24... And SOMA=40'
   WRITE(*,*) 'L = ', L
   SOMA = DEZASSEIS + L
   WRITE(*,*) 'SOMA = ', SOMA
   END PROGRAM carla
```

I would expect L=LM=24... And SOMA=40...
But instead I get:

```
   L =           25
   SOMA =           41
```

I don't understand why once we are outside of the DO loop, L does not keep the last value assumed (SOMA would be thus equal to 40), and keep increasing...

Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: So what are the values of L and SOMA you are seeing after the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop from 1 to 24,
So when it gets to 25, loop has finished.

```
Think of it as 
(pseudocode)
LL = 1
While LL < 25
 LL = LL + 1;
```

As GummiV stated, don't do this. Loops are prime targets for compiler optimisations, no guarantee what's in there after the loop has executed. Could have just as easily been 0, one optimisation reverses the count because detecting LL = 0 is quicker than LL > 24 on some machines. Not much quicker, but compiler guys have a real problem with it'll do.

Comment: "Could have just as easily been 0" -- no, the rules of Fortran specify the value of the loop variable after the loop.  Something else is a compiler bug.

Comment: That would depend on the compiler, and even if true for all of them in Fortran. It's certainly not true for other languages / compilers. Save yourself a lot of trouble and don't use the loop variable out side of the loop.

Comment: I don't want to use the loop variable outside of the loop!
This question arised from an error in the code - one variable was being used outside the loop (but it was already corrected) - and I wanted to understand the behaviour of the model when it was running that old code...

Comment: Never said you wanted to, but you were, which gave you behaviour you didn't expect, which I explained and you accepted the answer. My comment was to @M.S.B, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Tony: It won't depend on the compiler, unless it has a bug. I see absolutely no reason not to use the value of the loop variable outside of the loop. As has been said, it is clearly defined. What other languages do, is of no importance.

Comment: I see a reason. The same one that tripped up the OP. The value might be clearly defined but it isn't clear. As for what other languages do or don't not being important, some of us code in more than one. Developing good habits across languages is simple self defense.

Answer (score 4):

Fortran doesn't work that way. ( it's not Matlab :P )

> Exercise caution if using the index variable outside the DO loop
>   because the variable is incremented at the end of the loop, i.e., it
>   will be stepsize more than the final value.

http://www.oc.nps.edu/~bird/oc3030_online/fortran/do/do.html

Which explains why `L=25` after the loop.

*Edit: The following is incorrect. See M.S.B.'s comment below*

> *In Fortran the DO-variable ... should never be referenced outside the loop without first explicitly assigning a value to it.* - http://www.esm.psu.edu/~ajm138/fortranexamples.html

Comment: The posters question shows that the value of L is 25, which is exactly what is expected from the rules of Fortran as you have quoted.   I think the statement that a DO-variable should never be referenced outside of a loop is over-stated and should not be taken as a "law" ... a typical practice to avoid confusion, OK.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've edited my answer per your comment. (The orginal poster must have edited his equestion shortly after posting but I failed to refresh before posting, I could swear the L=25 info was not there when I replied)

Comment: Your link at [psu](http://www.esm.psu.edu/~ajm138/fortranexamples.html) should not taken too seriously: the first example is obviously bound to fail on compilers using "static" local variables, as is explained in example 2. Teaching bad tricks, and even failing on DO loops as you noticed.

Comment: As @eriktous comments under the other answer, the value outside the loop is defined perfectly well and referencing the value is perfectly OK.